# Find out feature version for list's content type

Tags: list, content-type, upgrade, versioning, feature-upgrade

I have a feature which contains a custom content type. I've created a list based on this content type then proceeded into changing the feature version and performing an upgrade.

I have `PushDown="TRUE"` on the `<AddContentTypeField>` element of `<UpgradeActions>` and I want to see if the upgrade was propagated to the list.

How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/Wikipage) - its a codeplex solution that you run on your server.  With it, you'll be able to navigate into a site and review the CAML associated with the content types that have been deployed to a site.

- Be sure to do a *Run As Administrator* on SharePoint Manager 2010 after extracting it
- Using the explorer, navigate into the site you've deployed the content type to.
- Expand the content types node, select your content type and move to the ***Schema Xml*** tab on the left had pane to view the XML of the content type.

Good luck.